# Why is my toast showing up twice? Console.log only runs once

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

I'm integrating websockets in my app, and I use useEffect with conversation as dependency. The console.log runs only once, however the `toast.add()` shows the toast twice, when conversation is null. Why is that?

My function is as follows:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        let handler;

        if (socket) {
            handler = data => {
                if (!conversation || conversation._id !== data.message.conversationId) {
                    console.log(conversation)
                    toast.add(`New message from ${data.message.user.displayName}`);
                }
            };

            io.onConversation(handler);
        }

        return () => {
            console.log('conversation handler off');
            io.offConversation(handler);
        }
    }, [socket, conversation]);
```

Comment: are you sure toast.add is not run anywhere else? also are you sure running toast.add once only shows toast once?

Comment: the toast shows up only once if i havent sent a message to a different recipient, however when i send a message, and go to home page, setting conversation to null, it runs twice

Comment: if conversation has data, the toast shows up only once. if its null, it shows up twice

Answer (score 0):

Because `useEffect` will tear down the previous handler and set up a new one when `conversation` becomes `null`, and because the `if` statement inside your handler will evaluate `true` when `conversation` is `null`. I would write it something like this:

```js
useEffect(function () {
    if (socket == null || conversation == null) return;

    function handler(data) {
        if (conversation._id !== data.message.conversationId) {
            toast.add(`New message from ${data.message.user.displayName}`);
        }
    }

    io.onConversation(handler);
    return function () {
        io.offConversation(handler);
    }
}, [socket, conversation]);
```

Comment: i want the handler to run when conversation is null

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out why it's not been working. it's something to do with the toast hook, which i copied from the internet. Now I'm using `npm i react-notifications-component` and its working as intended.